# Upload external image to fs.grid with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using MongoDb, and I want to upload a remote image (for example: put the URL in a $var and upload to my mongo instance). I try a lot of things, like using file_get_contents, curl, etc.

Do you have a example for this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There are already many examples to be found in the [MongoGridFS documentation](http://www.php.net/MongoGridFS). Specifically, I would suggest reading entries for the `put()` and `store*()` methods.

Additionally, you may find [this blog post](http://learnmongo.com/posts/getting-started-with-mongodb-gridfs/) helpful, although it is a bit dated. The comments on that blog post also reference [Thundergrid](https://github.com/imjacobclark/Thundergrid), which is a small PHP application for managing GridFS uploads. You're likely to find code examples by perusing its source on GitHub.